# Putting together 2 drop down lists where second is taking data based on the selected option on the first

Tags: php, html, mysql

the below code shows the option for only one drop down list but I would like to have more. For example, if I choose color green in the first drop down, to give me the options only for that color within the second drop down like: light green, dark green. Should I repeat the below code for each drop down list?

```
# here database details      
mysqli_connect('hostname', 'username', 'password');
mysqli_select_db('database-name');

$sql = "SELECT username FROM userregistraton";
$result = mysqli_query($sql);

echo "<select name='username'>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['username'] ."'>" . $row['username'] ."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

# here username is the column of my table(userregistration)
# it works perfectly
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: dont use the mysql driver, its deprecated and removed in 7.

Comment: thank you @DevDonkey! but still my question would remain :)

Comment: you need to use some AJAX which fires off an `onchange` event from the first one, pulls data in from your php script, then updates the options on the 2nd.

Comment: this sounds quite clear. Do you maybe have some example code which I can take and follow as logic on mine? Thank you!